# HTML, CSS, JavaScript automatic image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day guys, i was trying to create a image slider of both html, css and javascripts, am still a novice at javascript, am not good at it that much, but i stugled and find my way out of this, but not totally because am having some little challenges on it. My was that i create the slider successfully but i was unable to remove the images that are not active, i want the none active images to disappear the moment an activate get slided on. below is my code snippest:

```js
var imageSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('imageSlides');
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
var counter = 0

function hideImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
        imageSlides[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }
}  

function removeDots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
        circles[i].classList.remove('dot');
    }
}

function imageLoop() {
    var currentImage = imageSlides[counter];
    var currentDot = circles[counter];
    currentImage.classList.add('visible');
    removeDots();
    currentDot.classList.add('dot');
    counter++;
}

function slideshow() {
    if (counter < imageSlides.length) {
        imageLoop();
    } else {
        counter = 0;
        hideImages();
        imageLoop();
    }
}

setTimeout(slideshow, 1000);
var imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 10000);
```

```css
.slideshowContainer {
   /* position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px 0 75px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;*/
}

.imageSlides {
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 50%;
    top: 50%;*/
    transform: translate();
    /*min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 0;
}

.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}

.slideshowCircles {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.circle {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dot {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border: solid 2px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshowContainer">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="https://www.imagesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Rio.jpg" style="width:100%;height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="http://blog.entheosweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/headergreen.jpg" style="width:100%;height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="https://hkr.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/hi-tech-concepts-on-blue-background-header.jpg" style="width:100%; height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>

  <div class="slideshowCircles" style="text-align:center">
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code worked actually, it was successful but the moment an image that are not the same in width and height are been captured, i noticed that all the imges a been showed but are been loop over one after the other, which i dont want the image without a dot to show at all. i create a function to remove the image but i dont think that fucntion is working at all. I will be grateful if this is been solved through you!

THANKS...

Comment: Can you move your snippet to a executable JS/HTML/CSS snippet? I was going to move it for you but the code doesn't show any images

Comment: @MarioPerez I don't really get what you're saying?

Comment: take a look at this thread https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Comment: @MarioPerez have turned it into a snippet

Answer (score 0):

```js
var imageSlides = document.getElementsByClassName('imageSlides');
var circles = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
var counter = 0

function hideImages() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
        imageSlides[i].classList.remove('visible');
    }
}  

function removeDots() {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageSlides.length; i++) {
        circles[i].classList.remove('dot');
    }
}

function imageLoop() {
    var currentImage = imageSlides[counter];
    var currentDot = circles[counter];
    currentImage.classList.add('visible');
    removeDots();
    currentDot.classList.add('dot');
    counter++;
}

function slideshow() {
    if (counter < imageSlides.length) {
        imageLoop();
    } else {
        counter = 0;
        hideImages();
        imageLoop();
    }
}

setTimeout(slideshow, 1000);
var imageSlideshowInterval = setInterval(slideshow, 10000);
```

```css
.slideshowContainer {
   /* position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px 0 75px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;*/
}

.imageSlides {
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 50%;
    top: 50%;*/
    transform: translate();
    /*min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 0;
}

.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}

.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}

.slideshowCircles {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.circle {
    display: none;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dot {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border: solid 2px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshowContainer">
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="https://www.imagesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Rio.jpg" style="width:100%;height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="http://blog.entheosweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/headergreen.jpg" style="width:100%;height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img class='imageSlides' src="https://hkr.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/hi-tech-concepts-on-blue-background-header.jpg" style="width:100%; height:  auto;margin-bottom: 40px !important;">
  </a>

  <div class="slideshowCircles" style="text-align:center">
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
    <span class="circle dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```